# how to show only Large icon without small when use NotificationCompat without using small

Tags: android

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(b)
            .setContentTitle("this a message!")
            .setContentText("Hello world");
```

can I use only setLagreIcon() or any other alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html):

> A Notification object must contain the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
> - A title, set by setContentTitle()
> - Detail text, set by setContentText()

So no, this is not possible.

Edit: A really **unsafe and not recommended** method seems to be explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33943309/4908802).

Comment: I have seen the documentation. but I discover that many other app's notification are displayed only large bitmap.can you explain the issue?thanks !

Comment: Are you sure they only use the `largeIcon`? I know there are many issues with a non white small icon. I added a method to accomplish this in my answer, I have not tried it myself.